# I can't figure out how to start up Minecraft Java Edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I downloaded Minecraft Java Edition on my Windows 11 and downloaded the launcher, but I can't open the actual Minecraft. When I open the launcher, it sends me to the "Welcome to Minecraft" screen and when I do press install (I pressed "I have read terms and conditions" before that) it stops on the "Making things awesome" screen.

I bought it off of the actual Minecraft site.

Comment: Is there anything on your taskbar asking you to provide permission for Minecraft to modify your hard drive?

Comment: Yes but I think I already gave permission

Answer (score 1):

You need to be logged in Microsoft Store with the Microsoft Account you used to buy the game. The new launcher does not (cannot?) do that and it doesn't tell you the problem.
Try this:

1. Close the launcher and open Microsoft Store
2. Login in Microsoft Store with the Microsoft Account you use for Minecraft.
3. Start the launcher again.

The new launcher still has some problems like the one above and also there is another thing that happens often:
The launcher will want to log you in Xbox Live. It can do that automatically but it doesn't wait long enough and reports an error. Wait a few seconds and try again in that case.